# Using Gulp to publish ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, gulp, publish

I would like to use a gulp task to compile and publish my ASP.NET application and integrate it in my overall release. I tried to find something via google and on StackOverflow, but I was not successful. Visual Studio (2015) is also not very helpful, as it does not show which commands it uses (if this is not an internal process).

I would like to get the same output as selecting my project -> Publish... (see image)

[image: Publish Visual Studio]

Is this possible somehow? Has anybody automated this or do I have to use the TFS build system to do it? Or does somebody know if I can use VisualStudio on my command line to automate the process?

**EDIT:**

It is currently an asp.net 4.5.1 application.

Comment: Its Core or .net? For asp.net core in Project.json file you can set tasks to be executed before and after publish.  http://image.prntscr.com/image/3cb02330187c4eedab37eb0a2c0f949d.png

Comment: It is .net 4.5.1, sadly. But we plan to move to .net core when the odata v4 stuff works on .net core (or we can get it to work). Thanks for that hint!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, thanks to whoever voted for this question, I forgot about it.

Here is my example:

```
gulp.task("publishaspdotnet", (done: DoneCallback) => {
    const gatewayBuildSolutionName = "My.sln"; // maybe also .csproj possible
        exec("msbuild " + gatewayBuildSolutionName + " /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=localrelative /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=\"" + target + "\"", logConsoleOutput).on("exit", () => {
            gutil.log("Really done --------------------------------------");
            done();
        });
    });
});
```

Here are the steps:

1. Create a publish profile for your ASP.NET project (right click on your project -> publish...)
2. You can edit the profile, just click on "show all folders" in your solution explorer, go to publish profiles and edit your profile to deploy relative to the .csproj file which the pubxml file belongs to. The publishUrl tag is the place your code gets published to (if you set to local)
3. Write your gulp task and use msbuild to build. Use the switches as shown in the example above and reference your publish profile there. Now publish will be executed